# SASS in 1.9 - LESS in 2 - Why?

Tags: css, magento-1.9, magento2, sass

As I familiarize myself with Magento's implementation of SASS, I recalled this bit from the Magento 2 wiki:

https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/CSS+Preprocessing+in+Magento+2#CSSPreprocessinginMagento2-AdoptionofLESS

There is specifically one point that seems confusing:

> LESS implementation does not extend Magento 2 requirements with any
>   external libraries, like node.js.

Why the difference between CSS preprocessors between versions? I understand that Magento 2 is a wholly new version, but it seems awkward that SASS would be chosen in 1.9 only to be abandoned in 2.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Alan Kent himself (eBay Search VP, M2 product technical lead):

> SASS is more powerful than LESS, and appears to be gaining more market
>   share over LESS.  So why did Magento 2 choose LESS? Sorry, a boring
>   pragmatic reason:
>
> At the time we had to commit to a technology, there were several
>   stable LESS pre-processors available in PHP, but no (stable) PHP
>   implementations for SASS.

The M2 team had put a lot of deliberation and thought into the long-term support of the product beyond the launch date and the amount of risk they were willing to assume. They also needed a LESS/SASS PHP compiler that was a specific license to be able to incorporate into M2. This posed an issue as the most popular PHP SASS compiler is a (somewhat) **dormant project** maintained by **only one developer**. Again, this was a deliberate process in the selection.

The CE 1.9/1.14 SASS implementation took a different path to implementation as it was a collaborative effort from 3rd party partners (Classy Llama and Brendan Falkowski) to license a pre-existing framework that Brendan had created and used on multiple builds, [including the famous SkinnyTies.com implementation](http://gravitydept.com/blog/responsive-ecommerce-part-two). This was already built in SASS and was to be repurposed by the [3M site build](http://www.shop3m.com/) that is touted in the release announcement. 3M was Classy's client and <strike>they contracted Brendan to help them deliver it</strike> while also being commissioned from Magento 1 team to make it part of the framework. The effort to deliver on-time was driven by the fact that the framework was **already in-use** and somewhat developed prior to the BF/CL endeavor. Long term support here is probably not such a desperate consideration because of:

- The proximity of the M2 launch (ETA some time EOY 2015)
- There is no runtime CSS compilation (M2 requires it)
- SASS is entirely optional. It is possible to use the new responsive framework without ever recompiling SASS.

### TL;DR

<speculation>The decisions were seemingly made insular from each other.</speculation>

Source:

http://alankent.wordpress.com/2014/06/21/magento-2-less-versus-sass-decision/

Comment: So is this to say that M2 will require the use of LESS instead of SASS?

Comment: M2 will support LESS Out of the Box - SASS implementations could be slotted in pretty easily. I imagine this will happen pretty quickly (could happen even today)

Comment: I think yes. But if they did it right (and I think they did), you can exchange LESS and SASS quite easy.

Comment: There's an untold story behind Sass in 1.x for another time. Just a clerical note that the 3M project was Classy Llama only and uses a framework internal to 3M so it's probably the worst reference implementation for the work Classy Llama and I did for Magento, but hey...timing.

Comment: `you can exchange LESS and SASS quite easy.` without making a completely new theme?